# "vbscript" find lines have the similar words separated by the colon " : "

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, compare, similarity, difference

I have a text file contains more than 5000 lines, each line has two words separated by colon eg( word1:word2 )
I need a script compares the (word1) with (word2) on each line if they exactly matched it saves the line as it in a new text file. 
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Why don't you put the slightest bit of effort into this yourself, instead of soliciting volunteers on the internet?

Comment: `for /?`, `if /?` `echo /?` and [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) is all, you need.

Comment: Your question title says VBSCRIPT but you used `batch-file` as one of your tags.  Which scripting language do you want to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just drag and drop your input file over this batch script and you will get a new file with the same word separated by a colon :

```bat
@echo off
Mode 70,3 & color 0A
Title Find lines have the similar words separated by a colon
set "ScriptName=%~nx0"
if "%~1"=="" goto error
echo(
echo      Find lines have the similar words separated by a colon
Set "OutputFile=newfile.txt"
If exist "%OutputFile%" Del "%OutputFile%"
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ('Type %1') do (
    If [%%a]==[%%b] echo %%a:%%b
)>>"%OutputFile%"
Start "" "%OutputFile%" & Exit
::****************************************************************
:Error
Mode 70,5 & color 0C
echo( & echo(
echo      You should drag and drop your file over "%ScriptName%"
Timeout /T 5 /nobreak>nul & exit
::****************************************************************
```

Comment: Works perfect, Thank you very much.

Comment: @AhmedAbotaleb You are welcome ;) if this answer helped you don't forget to accept it !
Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Done, Thanks a lot for your help.